# Java, comparing singlecharacter string to character

Tags: java

Is there an easy way of comparing a string (which you know to contain only a single character) to a character? The method I am currently using feels a bit "clunky".

```
c == "x".charAt(0)
```

Where c is a character. The reason I am using "x" (string) is because I don't know how to write x as a char, so I have to do this.

Comment: `'x'` is x as character. So... `if (myString.charAt(0) == 'x')`

Comment: Eclipse complains (not yet compilable code, defining methods atm). If I do c=="." it complains about comparing string to char.

Comment: So it is actually compilable? I am trating Eclipse like my God here since I am completely new to Java and letting it teach me.

Comment: If you are sure the string contains only a single character, then store it as a character i.e. `char c = 'x'`

Comment: Can you post your full code (if it's not humungously large)...

Comment: Oh wow thank you for the comments, one of those occasions when you feel really dumb for not having figured this out earlier, I did go over the oracle and java docs on characters, I just didn't understand what the problem was. It was me using double quotations (") instead of (') to assign a char, I just thought the docs meant (").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'x'` is a char, `"x"` is a String.

### Solution

```
c == 'x'
```

See [Java Tutorial: Characters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)

### Note

```
"x".equals(Character.toString(c))
```

does also work, but I would always take the first solution for the following reasons:

1. It is easier to read
2. It is more memory-efficient (a char needs 2 bytes, while a String with one character needs about 40 byte ([source](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/string_memory_usage.shtml)))
3. It is more time-efficient (no need to cast, no need for complicated object comparison)

Comment: Something tells me it won't always be `"x"`.

Comment: @A.R.S. The comment `I am trating Eclipse like my God here since I am completely new to Java` makes me sure that it is that simple.

Answer (score 2):

```
char c = 'c';
```

`'c'` is a character and `"x"` is a string.  `if ("x".equals(Character.toString(c)))` compares them.

As noted in the accepted answer, my comparison does have it's downsides, but is more dynamic.